# ModelBinding in asp.net mvc Beta1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I converted my web application from preview 3 to beta1 and am now trying to put the new functions of the framework to use. One of them is ModelBinding.

For this particular situation I created a class that is (for now) just a container of a bunch of simple-type properties.
If I create a form with a bunch of textboxes, I want the framework to fill a SearchBag instance with these fields.

- Where do I start?  Is this behaviour
  out of the box or do I implement a
  SearchBagBinder? I had a quick look
  at the IModelBinder but can't quite
  wrap my head around it and the
  DefaultModelBinder source doesn't
  make me any the wiser.
- What is this ModelBindingContext?
- How do I access my form fields?
- What if the values are not passed on
  by a form but rather by entering a
  URL directly?
- Where do I find up-to-date
  information on this (most blogs are
  outdated)? I thought I read a post
  by Phil at one time, but I can't
  seem to find it no more.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 3 votes, two stars, no answers :(

Comment: 3 votes because 3 people thought it was a good question, 2 stars because 2 people maked it as a favorite question and was interessted in tracking the replies.

Comment: I know what the stars and votes are for.. I was just being whiny boy venting my need for an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - Where do I start?  Is this behaviour
>     out of the box or do I implement a
>     SearchBagBinder? I had a quick look
>     at the IModelBinder but can't quite
>     wrap my head around it and the
>     DefaultModelBinder source doesn't
>     make me any the wiser.

It is out of the box.  You can either use UpdateModel or ModelBinder to acheive what you are looking to do.

> - What is this ModelBindingContext?

This contains all the necessary information for the request to be bound to your Model.  Similar to ControllerContext and ActionFilterContext, it is basically the state of the ModelBinder and contains all the information necessary to do what you want, if you follow the ASP.NET MVC teams recommendations for what the ModelBinder is supposed to do.

> - How do I access my form fields?

```
context.HttpContext.Request.Forms["myformfield"];
```

or

```
foreach (var field in context.HttpContext.Request.Forms.Keys) {
    var value = context.HttpContext.Request.Forms[field];
}
```

> - What if the values are not passed on
>     by a form but rather by entering a
>     URL directly?

If you need to check both the Form and the QueryString just loop through both collections.

```
foreach (var field in context.HttpContext.Request.Forms.Keys) {
    var value = context.HttpContext.Request.Forms[field];
}
foreach (var field in context.HttpContext.Request.QueryStrings.Keys) {
    var value = context.HttpContext.Request.QueryStrings[field];
}
```

or you can loop through Param which will contain, Form, QueryString, Headers, etc.

```
foreach (var field in context.HttpContext.Request.Params.Keys) {
    var value = context.HttpContext.Request.Params[field];
}
```

> - Where do I find up-to-date
>     information on this*(most blogs are
>     outdated)? I thought I read a post
>     by Phill at one time, but I can't
>     seem to find it no more.

You have it right Phil is the best place for information as the PM of ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: I never found where these tutorials were talking about when they mentioned HttpContext. I didn't get that property..
Untill I added System.Web.Routing to my references! Doh! Thanks a bunch